# Blower electrical issues

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply

[image]I have acquired a low cfm/high suction pressure blower for performing some in-house R&D. The blower comes with a driver and has closer to eight leads. Will the interconnection of the leads from the driver have any effect on the blower's performance? Because the blower hasn’t survived for more than a couple of weeks. Can anyone with a better understanding of the blower EE help me out? The blower is rated at 11.5 amps, and the SMPS I have has an output of 8 Amps. Trying to identify the root cause of the problem. Any help will be appreciated. Attached is the blower

[image]

Comment: If you have a datasheet, add it to your question to help inform people's answers

Comment: AJM - Welcome :) As you're new here, please see the [tour] & [help] for the main site rules, as they differ from a typical forum. || Your question is missing details at the moment. Please [edit] it and add datasheets for the blower & driver, as already mentioned. Also explain *exactly* what you mean by "*the blower hasn’t survived for more than a couple of weeks*" e.g. what do you mean by "survived"? Do you do something to fix that? "*Trying to identify the root cause of the problem.*" What *exactly* what you mean by "problem". And why did you choose an SMPS rated less than the blower? Thanks.

Comment: @SamGibson. Thank you so much for the welcoming message and the suggestion of adding the images. As i'm new around here I had no clue how it is to be done. But yes, I have copied them. The blower has been used to remove the gases from an incinerator and the gases are allowed to cool using small heat exchangers of sufficient cooling and a filter. So the blower can be subjected to exhaust gases as medium. The SMPS was chosen by an EE and he informed me that the suggested SMPS will work. Since he was not being very responsive I decided to take matters into my own hands and here I am.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will take a SWAG and say you are frying the motor. The solution is to either get a smaller motor or a bigger SMPS.

Comment: Working on procuring a new SMPS as we speak. Much appreciate your time! Can't believe the electrical engineer who suggested and added the SMPS was not aware of this. I'm very much grateful to you Gil. Thanks, Chief!